# Notation of Block Matrix

Tags: matrices, notation, block-matrices

How does the notation of a block matrix work? I'm sorry if my question is not specific, but I would really appreciate an answer with an example.

Comment: This question is completely missing of context. What do you mean by "block matrix"?

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic to it.  Let's say that A, B, C, and D are all matrices.  Then
\begin{bmatrix}
  A & B \\ C & D
\end{bmatrix}
is a block matrix (where here we are assuming that the matrices $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ have the right dimensions so that the block matrix works out.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: is this a matrix of matrix then (a collection of matrix)? or just a notation

Comment: The two are isomorphic (with pointwise addition and scalar multiplication).  Strictly speaking, I guess it depends on how you're using it.  But since they're isomorphic, you can always use the isomorphism to translate one to the other.  I guess that's what's done implicitly.

Comment: perfect, I agree