# Derivation of Linear Regression using Normal Equations

Tags: matrix-calculus, linear-regression

I was going through Andrew Ng's course on ML and had a doubt regarding one of the steps while deriving the solution for linear regression using normal equations.

Normal equation: $\theta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$

While deriving, there's this step:

$\frac{\delta}{\delta\theta}\theta^TX^TX\theta = X^TX\frac{\delta}{\delta\theta}\theta^T\theta$

But isn't matrix multiplication commutative, for us to take out $X^TX$ from inside the derivative?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two symmetric $(A, B)$ consider these following the scalar functions and their gradients
$$\eqalign{
\alpha &= \theta^TA\theta &\implies \frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial\theta}=2A\theta \cr
 \beta &= \theta^TB\theta &\implies \frac{\partial\beta}{\partial\theta}=2B\theta \cr
}$$
It's not terribly illuminating, but you ***can*** write the second gradient in terms of the first, i.e.
$$\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial\theta} = BA^{-1}\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial\theta}$$ 
For the purposes of your question, $A=I$ and $B=X^TX$.

Answer (score 2):

Although that equality is true, it does not give insight into why it is true.

There are many ways to compute that gradient, but here is a direct approach that simply computes all the partial derivatives individually.

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix. (In your context, $A=  X^\top X$.)
The partial derivative of $\theta^\top A \theta = \sum_i \sum_j A_{ij} \theta_i \theta_j$ with respect to $\theta_k$ is
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_k} \theta^\top A \theta = \sum_i \sum_j A_{ij} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_k}(\theta_i \theta_j) = A_{kk} \cdot 2 \theta_k + \sum_{i \ne k} A_{ik} \cdot \theta_ i + \sum_{j \ne k} A_{kj} \theta_j = 2\sum_i A_{ki} \theta_i = 2 (A \theta)_k$$
Stacking the partial derivatives into a vector gives you the gradient, so
$$\nabla_\theta \theta^\top A \theta = 2 A \theta.$$

Answer (score 0):

A slight generalization of the result in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3072420/252983) is a matrix identity that I believe Andrew Ng may have pointed out at some stage. Although it is not needed for this problem, it's useful to know in general. For any matrices $Z, A$ with $A$ symmetric we have:

$$\nabla_Z tr(Z^TAZ) = 2AZ$$

I believe Andrew Ng introduces something like this as the matrix analogy for the case of $\frac{\delta}{\delta x}x^2 = 2x$, where $x$ is just a scalar. In this case, $\nabla_Zf(Z)$ is just the matrix of partial derivatives of the function $f$ with respect to each entry in some general $m \times n$ matrix $Z$ and $tr(A)$ is the sum of the diagonals of a square matrix $A$. The only difference here to the linked answer is that the linked answer shows the identity's truth for the case where $Z = \theta$ is a vector (rather than a general matrix). But we can generalize further by induction on the number of columns $n$ in $Z$. Clearly, the [linked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3072420/252983) gives us the truth for $n = 1$, where the trace of the scalar result is just the result itself. So we're only left with the inductive case.

In the inductive case, we will make use of [block notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778730/notation-of-block-matrix) for matrices which is very handy for induction on matrices. So we assume the identity holds for all $m \times n'$ matrices with $n' \leq n$ and show that it holds for any $m \times (n + 1)$ matrix. Well, using block notation, such a matrix can always be written as an $m \times n$ matrix concatenated with a vector. So we have:

$$Z = \begin{bmatrix} Z' & \theta \end{bmatrix}$$

Where $\theta$ is some $m \times 1$ matrix i.e. a vector. Now, we can start using algebra to transform the above expression:

$$Z^TAZ = 
\begin{bmatrix} Z' & \theta \end{bmatrix}^TA\begin{bmatrix} Z' & \theta \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} Z'^T \\ \theta^T \end{bmatrix}A\begin{bmatrix} Z' & \theta \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} Z'^TA \\ \theta^TA \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} Z' & \theta \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} Z'^TAZ' & Z'^TA \theta\\ \theta^TAZ' & \theta^TA \theta \end{bmatrix}$$

What we've just done is expanded the matrix out into its four quadrants. Now recall that we're interested in the trace of the matrix. A nice property of traces of matrices written in four quadrants like the above is that the trace completely discards the upper right and lower left quadrants. So we have:

$$
tr \begin{bmatrix} Z'^TAZ' & Z'^TA \theta\\ \theta^TAZ' & \theta^TA \theta \end{bmatrix} = tr(Z'^TAZ') + tr(\theta^TA\theta)
$$

Now, since $Z = \begin{bmatrix} Z' & \theta \end{bmatrix}$, we can split the matrix derivative of $Z$ for any function $f$ using block notation as follows:

$$\nabla_Zf(Z) = \begin{bmatrix} \nabla_{Z'}f(Z) & \nabla_\theta f(Z) \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, putting these last facts together, we have:

$$
\nabla_Z tr \begin{bmatrix} Z'^TAZ' & Z'^TA \theta\\ \theta^TAZ' & \theta^TA \theta \end{bmatrix} =
\nabla_Z (tr(Z'^TAZ') + tr(\theta^TA\theta)) = \\
\begin{bmatrix} \nabla_{Z'}(tr(Z'^TAZ') + tr(\theta^TA\theta)) & \nabla_\theta (tr(Z'^TAZ') + tr(\theta^TA\theta)) \end{bmatrix}
$$

An important fact assumed but not yet made explicit that we'll now use is that all the entries in our matrix $Z$ are independent of each other. In particular, this implies that $Z'$ and $\theta$ are independent of each other. And so the derivatives w.r.t $Z'$ and $\theta$ can simplify as follows:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \nabla_{Z'}(tr(Z'^TAZ') + tr(\theta^TA\theta)) & \nabla_\theta (tr(Z'^TAZ') + tr(\theta^TA\theta)) \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} \nabla_{Z'} tr(Z'^TAZ') & \nabla_\theta tr(\theta^TA\theta) \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, finally, we can apply our inductive hypothesis to both block components of our matrix, since both $\theta$ and $Z'$ are smaller than $Z$ (and $\theta$ was our base case anyway), to get:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \nabla_{Z'} tr(Z'^TAZ') & \nabla_\theta tr(\theta^TA\theta) \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 2AZ' & 2A\theta \end{bmatrix} = 2A\begin{bmatrix} Z' & \theta \end{bmatrix} = 2AZ
$$

And that completes the proof. Again, it's overkill for what you need for this exact case, but it's a more general identity that you may want to apply in other scenarios where $Z$ may not be a vector.